# Can not copy from Excel and paste to a Form Edit restricted Word document unless restriction is turned off

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, copy-paste

I am copying Excel cell contents to a bookmark on a Form Edit restricted (2010) Word document but it will only paste if the protection is turned off.

The code I currently have to turn the protection on again afterwards errors.  What is the correct code?

Is there a way to make this copy and paste without turning off the protection?

Second problem is that when the text is pasted to the bookmark the font is Red (if manually entered on the document it is in black).  The Word default is set as black (I reset the default for good measure).  Typing in a new document is in black, however, when Word opens the font icon shows red even though checking the default it is still shows black.  Can I define the font colour in the VBA to override this issue until is is resolved or can you suggest a way to fix the Word default?

```
Sub Arzbericht_Brandstetter()

' x - Defined Cell Names -  ARTBrandPATH   ,  ARTBrandDOC

'                               Excel          Word Bookmark
' x - Defined Cell Names -  ARZKrankenhaus       Text65


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim Wd As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim BrandstetterDoc As Object
Dim BrandstetterPath As String

Dim f As Boolean

BrandstetterPath = ActiveSheet.Range("ARTBrandPATH").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("ARTBrandDOC").Value & ".doc"  ' x

'    On Error Resume Next

Set BrandstetterDoc = GetObject(BrandstetterPath)

If BrandstetterDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set Wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Wd Is Nothing Then
        Set Wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        If Wd Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Failed to start Word!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        f = True
    End If
    Set BrandstetterDoc = Wd.Documents.Open(BrandstetterPath)
    If BrandstetterDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open Brandstetter Document!" & vbNewLine & _
                   " Check File Directory is correct", vbCritical
        If f Then
            Wd.Quit
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Wd.Visible = True
Else
    With BrandstetterDoc.Parent
        .Visible = True
        .Activate


'  Turn Protection OFF
        With ActiveDocument
            .Unprotect "xxxxx"
            .Protect wdAllowOnlyRevisions, , Password:="xxxxx"
        End With

        BrandstetterDoc.Bookmarks("Text65").Range.Text = ws.Range("ARZKrankenhaus").Value


'  Turn Protection ON   (Restricted Editing)
'           ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True

    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because its a Formfield and not just a bookmark I changing the code as below which resolved the strange red font issue.  I can now copy to the document protected.

```
From
BrandstetterDoc.Bookmarks("Text65").Range.Text = ws.Range("ARZKrankenhaus").Value
To
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text65").Result = ws.Range("ARZKrankenhaus").Value
```